# I made a mistake while typing migrate:fresh does it have a way to recover deleted data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i made a big mistake guys. i run `php artisan migrate:fresh` on the production server.
please guys, does it have a way to recover deleted data (users etc.)

Comment: Does you server run backups of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Customer Support of the server, they have a backup for your database. I hope you will get it. Backup is running in the background.

Comment: Hello, i've contacted the customer support. Indeed, they had the backup of the database. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`migrate:fresh` drops all the tables and rebuilds the entire database. This is a more drastic data dumping than just deleting each row in each table. Unless you can restore from backup, your data is unfortunately gone.

In order to attempt to prevent this from happening in the future, I'd suggest adding the following line to your `.env` file. It will cause Laravel to ask you before doing something that could lose data, such as doing a migration:

```
# .env
APP_ENV=production
```

Once this line is here, doing a migrate will pop up the following confirmation:

```
$ ./artisan migrate:fresh --seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > no

$ echo 'whew... that was a close one'
```

Comment: Hello, i've contacted the customer support. Indeed, they had the backup of the database. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The deleted data would be still on your computer until the deleted data is occupied by the new data. Before the deleted data is overwritten, it is recoverable. Generally, you can get the deleted data back on your computer with a computer data recovery tool that can support Windows/Mac operating systems.

Here are the steps to recover your deleted data on the computer(applicable for most tools, like FoneDog Data Recovery):

1. Download and run the tool on your computer.
2. Select the data type you need to retrieve and the drive where the data is ever saved.
3. Scan the data in the drive.
4. Find out the deleted data and recover it.

Hope it could help you.